# Can't run Start-Process with RunAsUser from .ps1 file

Tags: windows, powershell, automation, scripting, runas

Wrote a script that copies a .exe file to a folder then tries to run it as another user but the Powershel window just closes without running the .exe.

The command that runs it works fine if I run it on the terminal but not when I try to run the .ps1 file with Powershell (the window just closes after copying the file). The command also works (wether i run the .ps1 file or the command on the terminal) if i try to run it as the local user instead of another user.

```
if (Test-Path -Path "C:\Users\Gustavo\Desktop\Teste") {
    Remove-Item -Path "C:\Users\Gustavo\Desktop\Teste" -Recurse -Force | Out-Null
}

New-Item -Path "C:\Users\Gustavo\Desktop\" -Name "Teste" -ItemType "directory" | Out-Null
Start-BitsTransfer -Source "C:\Users\Gustavo\Downloads\MediaCreationTool22H2.exe" -Destination "C:\Users\Gustavo\Desktop\Teste\" -Description "Backup" -DisplayName "Backup"

Start-Process -FilePath C:\Users\Gustavo\Desktop\Teste\MediaCreationTool22H2.exe -Verb RunAsUser
```

Comment: Start PS by right click shortcut and select Run As Admin.  Only and Admin or the User  Gustavo can access files in his user area.  PS does not automatically run as an admin.